# On the Total Number of Tries Required to have $n$ Successes

Tags: probability

**The Problem** A bag contains $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls. Balls are drawn at random from the bag until the last white ball is drawn. What is the expected number of balls drawn?

**My Partial Solution** Suppose the balls are lined up in a line and drawn from left to right. The number of balls to the left of the rightmost white ball (say $N$) ranges from $w-1$ to $w+b-1$, the number of balls to right is given by $w+b-N-1$. So, we can calculate the probability of each value of $N$ using the hypergeometric distribution, and we have

$\text{Expected number}=\displaystyle \sum_{k=w-1}^{b+w-1}\frac{\binom{k}{w-1}\binom{w+b-k-1}{0}}{\binom{w+b-1}{w-1}}\cdot\left(k+1\right)$

which requires computation of

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=w-1}^{b+w-1}\binom{k}{w-1} \cdot \left(k+1\right)$$

which I am unable to do.

Is my method even correct, and is there any easy way to do the problem or compute the sum?

Comment: Shall we take it that this is _without_ replacement?

Answer (score 3):

w balls will always be drawn. For every black ball, let x be the probability that it is drawn. Then the number you want, E = w + bx (using linearity of expectation, make indicator variables for each ball that are 1 if it is drawn else 0).

$x = \frac{w}{w+1}$ (probability that given black ball is not placed after all white balls).

So $E = w + \frac{bw}{w+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Let the black balls be labelled from $1$ to $b$. Imagine that we pick *all* of the balls, one at a time. Define the random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if black ball with label $i$ is **not** picked before all $w$ white balls are picked, and by $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Note that $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{w+1}$. For let $S_i$ consist of the $w$ white balls, and black ball $i$.  Black ball $i$ is picked at some time after all the white balls  precisely if it is the last ball in set $S_i$. Since all orderings of $S_i$ are equally likely, this proability is $\frac{1}{w+1}$. It follows that $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{w+1}$.

Let $X$ be the number of black balls that evade the picking process until all $w$ white balls are picked. Then
$X=\sum_1^b X_i$, and therefore
$$E(X)=\sum_1^b E(X_i)=\frac{b}{1+w}.$$
Note that the $X_i$ are *not* independent, but that does not matter for the expectation calculation.
The total number of trials in our actual situation is $w+b-X$, so has expectation $w+b-\frac{b}{1+w}$.

Answer (score 1):

The (essentially equivalent) approaches given by André and Wonder are simpler, but it is possible to finish off your approach by evaluating the sum:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=w-1}^{b+w-1}\binom{k}{w-1} \cdot \left(k+1\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^b\binom{w-1+k}{w-1}(w+k)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^b\frac{(w+k)!}{(w-1)!k!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^b\frac{w(w+k)!}{w!k!}\\\\
&=w\sum_{k=0}^b\binom{w+k}w\\\\
&=w\binom{w+b+1}{w+1}\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the last step uses [this identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#equation_10). However, you have the wrong denominator: it should be $\binom{w+b}w$, the total number of possible ways to place the white balls in the string, since there's no guarantee that the $(w+b)$-th ball is white. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Expected number}&=\displaystyle \sum_{k=w-1}^{b+w-1}\frac{\binom{k}{w-1}\binom{w+b-k-1}{0}}{\binom{w+b}w}\cdot\left(k+1\right)\\\\
&=\frac{w\binom{w+b+1}{w+1}}{\binom{w+b}w}\\\\
&=\frac{w(w+b+1)}{w+1}\\\\
&=w+\frac{bw}{w+1}\;.
\end{align*}$$