# Calculate number of trials reaching $p_k$ probability for $k$ successes given the $p_t$ probability of each trial success

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, statistics, numerical-methods, special-functions

Basically, I'd like to be able to answer questions in the form of "What is the number of trials needed to have at least $p_k$ probability of *at least* $k$ successes, given that on each trial the probability of success is $p_t$?".

Let $x$ be the number of trials, then the equation for the problem is:
$$\sum_{i=k}^x \frac{p_t^k(1-p_t)^{x-k}x!}{i!(x-i)!}\geq p_k\tag{*}\label{*} $$
We can also [determine lower bound](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46508075_Exact_bounds_on_the_probability_of_at_least_successes_in_exchangeable_Bernoulli_trials_as_a_function_of_correlation_coefficients) for $x$:$$x>\frac{p_k}k{p_t}$$

After some googling, I discovered that this exact question [has already been answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232464/how-many-tries-to-get-at-least-k-successes), but for small $k$'s normal approximation isn't applicable. I want to understand the problem deeper, so my questions are:

1. There's no analytical solution for \eqref{*}, since gamma-function is a special function and can't be integrated. Is that correct?
2. What's the best way to solve this numerically? May be there's another useful approximation or something more suitable than a simple root-finding algorithm.